# Show a list of my product with my coupon discount

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have 50 products. I used [ubercart module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) and [uc_coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_coupon) for my e-commence website. I have many different type of coupons for different products and I always make human mistakes and confuse.

Here is my question: Is there anyway to show a list of products with price and discount as well?

Answer (score 1):

==UPDATED==

Looks like you need views integration for the [UC Coupon Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_coupon), not fully supported yet.

Maybe you want to try and port [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1126586) to Drupal 7?

Comment: This module is for drupal 6. Mine is 7.

Comment: @learnallskill, scroll down the Module page  till "Downloads", where you will find several d7 releases.

Comment: Very sorry. Which link are you referring to? I Know UC couple module is version 7 (already download). Patch link what i see is version 
6.x-1.x-dev

Comment: thanks for clarifying this, @learnallskill. What you need is "Views Integration", not supported yet by themodule.  Answer updated. Hope will help.

Comment: thanks for your info. Since the module not ready. I hope I able to get alternate solution soon. :)

Comment: Sure. You can say thanks upvoting my answer. Good luck!